# Singly linked list counting algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm, singly-linked-list

I need to write a metod that goes over a sorted singly linked list and returns
the number that appears the most times but goes over the list only one time.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Can't find an elegent solution yet, should I use recursion?

I want the code to be as efficient as possible.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This should not be difficult, have you tried anything?

Comment: i know its a novice question, linked lists just dont sit right with me.. 
thanks for taking the time to read my question anyway

Answer (score 0):

You may use `HashMap<index,count>` 
traverse linked list 
if you find same number then incr count
at last check which count is great and return its index.

Comment: thanks for answering.. HashMap is not learned in my class so its not allowed, is there another way?

Answer (score 0):

```
 public int findMoreRecurrentValue(List<Integer> sortedList) {
    if(sortedList.size() == 0) return -1;
    int mostRecurrent = -1;
    int nReccurrences = 0;
    int n = 1;
    int current = sortedList.get(0);
    for(int i = 1; i < sortedList.size(); ++i) {
        if(sortedList.get(i) == current)
            ++n;
        else {
            if(n > nReccurrences) { 
                mostRecurrent = current;
                nReccurrences = n;
            }
            current = sortedList.get(i);
            n = 1;
        }
    }
    // Check again at the end, the most reccurrent value could be the last one.
    if(n > nReccurrences) {
        mostRecurrent = current;
        nReccurrences = n;
    }

    return mostRecurrent;
}
```

Comment: @EladNadav Your welcome :) If you're satisfied you should consider to accept the answer.

Comment: sorry i'm new to the site, how do i do that?

Comment: by the way how would you go about doing the same thing for a non sorted lined list?